# FontForge Interpolation Producing Jumbled Results

Tags: fontforge

I'm making a multi-weight font from a Thin weight and a Heavy weight. The glyphs that *were* correctly interpolated look good, but the ones that weren't look jumbled and terrible. (I know it looks like Verdana, don't remind me)
[image: The mostly correctly interpolated Regular weight.]

[I will provide the two fonts as raw .sfd files, and as .otf exports.](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/jpuopb3wf4gdl/MirageFont) Could you help me look into this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Check the number of points, the position of the first point (you can set the first point with CTRL-1), and the *direction* of the path.

Interpolation becomes especially tricky when there are multiple paths (e.g. any character with an enclosed counter such as *o* or *e*) or when it contains multiple references (letters with diacritics, for instance). You need to match up not just the points in each path, but also the *order* of the different paths and the order of different references. You can reorder paths and references by cutting and re-pasting them; this will move them to the top of the stack.

Unfortunately, path and reference ordering are not displayed. You can number your points (View>Number Points>SVG) which helps somewhat with ordering paths, though lines vs curves get numbered differently, so numbering won't always match exactly even between glyphs that interpolate just fine; also, this numbering lasts only as long as that glyph window is open; and none of this tells you anything about the ordering of references. It's a pain.

I usually just start cutting and re-pasting and use a process of elimination until I get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Make your contours compatible, ie. same number of points and same start points across masters.

Comment: I have already gone through the trouble to correspond the first point of each path. That's how I got the other 22 glyphs to work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by pasting each path onto a new glyph, corresponding glyphs in the same order.